# Running a VS 2017 project from VS 2019?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I'm new to Asp.Net.
I made a project (earlier) using VS 2017 which was working fine(last used).

Recently, I updated my VS 2017 to VS 2019; and now using VS 2019 my project is not running.

My earlier project (PersonDetails) resides in `C:\Users\HP\source\repos\PersonDetails` directory which contains the following files and folders:

- .vs
- packages
- PersonDetails
- PersonDetails.sln

Now when I try to run the project in VS 2019, on the browser it is displaying the following error

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
>       The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

```
Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

Things you can try:
If you do not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.
Enable directory browsing.
Go to the IIS Express install directory.
Run appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the server level.
Run appcmd set config ["SITE_NAME"] /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the site level.
Verify that the configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is set to true in the site or application configuration file.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     DirectoryListingModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x00000000
Requested URL      http://localhost:49236/
Physical Path      C:\Users\HP\source\repos\PersonDetails\PersonDetails
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous

More Information:
This error occurs when a document is not specified in the URL, no default document is specified for the Web site or application, and directory listing is not enabled for the Web site or application. This setting may be disabled on purpose to secure the contents of the server.
View more information »
```

Also when I'm building a new project in VS 2019 it is running properly. 
The new project (first) resides in `C:\Users\HP\source\repos\first` directory which has following files:

`.vs`

`bin`

`obj`

`properties`

`appsettings.Developement.json`

`appsettings.json`

`first.csproj`

`first.sln`

`Program.cs`

`Startup.cs`

WHAT COULD BE THE POSSIBLE MODIFICATIONS THAT COULD BE MADE IN ORDER TO RUN THE PROJECT (PersonDetails) IN VS 2019 ?

Thanx to those willing to help. :-)

Comment: Local debug settings are different for different versions of VS (these are stored under `.vs`). This includes the launch settings from the project's properties. Set them in VS2019 to match the settings you have in VS2017. (I am currently working on a project with a mix of 2017 and 2019 users.)

Comment: @Richard thanx for you reply. can you please suggest which file i have to edit as i am new in asp.net ? In my (PersonDetails) project >> `.vs` contains `config`(containing applicationhost.config file ) and `detailspage` contains folder `v15` which further consists of `server` folder and one `.suo` file.                                                         can you please explain in detail.      thanx for your efforts

Comment: Open the project, go to its properties, look at the debug tab

Comment: Could it be that you were opening your 2017 as an administrator? And now the 2019 not, sometimes you add this by default to the shortcut, when you upgrade, this is missing on the new shortcut. VS needs admin rights if the application is hosted in IIS. When you create a new web project, by default its hosted in IISExpress that doesn't need this rights.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly. I had the same problems before. Please click on your first project (.sln file) and  choose to open with vs 2019. After that, click on all projects that are in your solution explorer and choose to reload them.
When you reload all of them, click on your main project and choose to set as start.